# Generalisation of Nim

Tags: mathematics, game, algorithm, computer-science, nim

I'm asking for a general formula/algorithm that can be used in such a game.

> There are $n$ piles, with varying number of pebbles. The number of
>   pebbles in each pile is given by an array from $pile[1]$ to $pile[n]$.
>   There is another array called the $validmove[\ ]$ array. It has any
>   number of numbers. For example, we can define $validmove[\ ]=\{1,2,5,7\}$
>   This array is constant throughout the game.
>   If $0$ is present in $validmove$, it means that an entire pile can be removed,
>   irrespective of the number of pebbles it contains.
>
> 2 players play turnwise. On each turn, a player selects a single pile.
>   He may remove any number of pebbles, as long as that number is present
>   in the $validmove$ array. In the current example, suppose we have
>   selected a pile with $13$ stones. The player can now remove $1$, $2$,
>   $5$ or $7$ pebbles from that pile, leaving it with $12$, $11$, $8$ or
>   $6$ pebbles respectively.
>
> The person who removes the last stone wins (or I can specify 'loses'
>   as well, that may require a slightly different algorithm).
>
> If both players play perfectly, who wins?

I couldn't find an algorithm on the net, even though there is a huge Wikipedia page on it, so I thought SE could maintain one for future reference.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an open problem?

Comment: This problem is cool, but I think the solution won't be that easy. The Nim theory is quite complex (I mean, only for those who know a good bunch of math), its generalization is likely to be a pain. I'll give a try, though...

Comment: If 0 and 1 are not in $validmove[]$, it is possible for there to be no legal moves even though some stones remain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Sprague-Grundy theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem) gives an algorithm for determining the winning strategy.

First, we need to compute the [nimbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber) of various pile sizes. This is a finite computation if $validmove[]$ is finite. We will recursively define an array $nimber[]$. To start, define $nimber[0]=0$. For $n\geq 1$, we define
$$
nimber[n]=\mathrm{mex}\big\{nimber[n-k]: 1\leq k\in validmove,k\leq n \big\}.
$$
Here *mex* denotes the *minimum excluded* value, that is, the smallest non-negative integer which is not of the form $nimber[n-k]$. This is assuming $0$ is not in $validmove$; if it is, we should take the smallest positive integer instead.

Because $validmove$ is finite, the array $nimber$ will be eventually periodic. Each term only depends on the previous $N$ terms, where $N=\max validmove$, so we can stop computing once we see $N$ consecutive terms in $nimber[]$ that have already appeared previously as consecutive terms. This is guaranteed to happen, as none of the terms in $nimber$ can exceed the size of $validmove$. Actually, in all the examples I have computed (with $0$ not a valid move), $nimber$ turns out to be purely periodic, although it is not clear to me that this will always be the case.

Every game of generalized nim is equivalent to a game of ordinary nim, and a pile of size $k$ in generalized nim corresponds to a pile of size $nimber[k]$ in ordinary nim.

Once we have $nimber$ calculated, we need to evaluate $nimber[k]$ for $k=pile[1],\ldots,pile[n]$. If the nim sum (i.e., the binary xor) of these number is non-zero, the first player has a winning strategy. If the nim sum is zero, the second player has a winning strategy.

**Example**: Let's consider the example you gave: $validmove[]=\{1,2,5,7\}$. We recursively compute
$$
nimber[]=\{0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0\}.
$$
This means that in general,
$$
nimber[k]=\begin{cases}0: k\equiv 0\mod3,\\1:k\equiv 1\mod 3,\\2:k\equiv 2\mod 3.\end{cases}
$$
For any other array $validmove$, there will be a similar way to describe $nimber$ in terms of congruences, using a finite amount of data.

The nim sum of $nimber[pile[1]],\ldots,nimber[pile[n]]$ is $0$ if and only if the number of piles whose size is one more than a multiple of three is even, and the number of piles whose size is two more than a multiple of three is even. In this case, the second player can win, and otherwise the first player can win.

Comment: When 0 is not in the validmove array, this game is called a "finite subtraction game" or a "subtraction game with a finite subtraction set". The nimber sequence will *not* always be purely periodic. For example, if the validmove array is $\{3,4,6,10\}$, the nimber sequence (with commas and braces omitted since the nimbers are all less than $10$) is $00011122203314\overline{00201312}$. These types of games are discussed in many combinatorial game theory texts, including the undergraduate textbook "Lessons in Play: An Introduction to Combinatorial Game Theory" where the above example comes from.